# Using Yelp API lat/long in Folium -- CRS needed?

Tags: python, coordinate-system, api, jupyter-notebook, geoseries

I understand the default crs for Folium is EPSG3857. I am pulling lat/long data from a yelp query and am not sure if I need to be converting to a GeoSeries and assigning a CRS to the GeoSeries. It seems to be drawing fine, but I want to make sure I'm doing everything in the correct way. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: If you're getting latitude-longitude values (within +/-90 for latitude and +/-180 for longitude), then the CRS is EPSG:4326, not EPSG:3857.

Comment: Interesting. Those are my values, but when I try to define the crs as ESPG4326, the map doesn't render.